# My tkinter entry box is printing .!entry instead of what is entered

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *
def _name_():
              businessname=entry_bn
              print(businessname)
edit_bar=Tk()
name=Label(edit_bar,text="Name:").grid(row=0)
entry_bn=Entry(edit_bar)
entry_bn.grid(row=0,column=1)
submit=Button(edit_bar,text="Submit",command=_name_).grid(row=1,column=2)
```

Whenever i press my submit button, i get .!entry printed out, instead of what is entered into the entry box. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: `entry_bn.get()` is how you'd retrieve the text contained in the Entry.  You're printing out the Entry itself.

Comment: you're confusing the value in an entry widget with the entry widget itself. `entry_bn` represents the widget, not the value in the widget.

Comment: Thank ypu for the help, very silly question i realise now sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**:  i get `.!entry` printed out, instead of what is entered into the `Entry`

---

**Reference**:

- [Tkinter.Entry.get-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method)

  > Gets the current contents of the entry field. Returns the widget contents, as a string.

---

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        tk.Label(self, text="Name:").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.on_submit)
        btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')

    def on_submit(self):
        print('Name: {}'.format(self.entry.get()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```