# Want to add text in a Entry box to a .txt file on button click but im getting an error that says 'text' not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run this I get the error

```
 File "C:/Users/plarkin2020334/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/Start.py", line 24, in add_list
    file.write(text)
NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

I don't know why it won't run it but I think the basis of the code is right.

````
import tkinter
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = tkinter.Tk()


class FrameStart1(tkinter.Frame):
    image = PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/plarkin2020334/Pictures/DQ_Logocp.png')
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        Label(self, image=self.image).place(relx=0, rely=0, anchor=NW)
        Label(self, text="Enter any additional Instructiuons for the day:", background="#3f49e5").place(relx=.0, rely=.45)
        Button(self, text="Add to Todays List", command=self.add_list()).place(relx=.30, rely=.51)
        Entry(self).place(relx=.0, rely=.51)
        text = Entry.get()
    def add_list(self):
        file = open("List.txt", "w")
        file.write(text)


def runStart1():
    MyFrameStart1 = FrameStart1(root)
    MyFrameStart1.pack(expand='true', fill='both')
    MyFrameStart1.configure(background="#3f49e5")
    root.geometry("500x300")

runStart1()
root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: ***"NameError: name 'text' is not defined"***: That's correct, `text` in `file.write(text)` is not defined in `def add_list` and also not `global`. Read [scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)

Comment: so can i just make ```text```global

Comment: You are using `OOP class`, take the tour [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) for a better solution

Comment: i know that there messed up because of the class but i dont know where on that page the answer is

Comment: ***"messed up because of the class"***: There is nothing **messed up**, taken the tour at the given link you will learn how to define and access a `class member`.

Comment: i looked I just cant figure the problem out, im prob just stupid but I don't know?

Comment: After you get it working, you will be face this error: [get .!entry printed out, instead of what is entered into the Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59294399/7414759)

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to using classes, but wouldn't it have to be referenced as self.text since you are defining it in the `__init__` method?